# pgfgantt - Two labels for one bar in Gantt chart

Tags: labels, pgfgantt

In my Gantt chart (I'm using package `pgfgantt`), I have just one task in each line, one bar per task. Each bar has its corresponding label identifying the task aligned left of the chart; e.g.,

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
                    y unit chart=0.5cm,
                    vgrid={draw=none, dotted},
                    hgrid, 
                    title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
                    title left shift=.05,
                    title right shift=-.05,
                    title height=1,
                    bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
                    incomplete/.style={fill=white},
                    progress label text={},
                    bar height=0.7,
                    group right shift=0,
                    group top shift=.6,
                    group height=.3,
                    group peaks={}{}{.2}]{12}

    \gantttitle{2012}{12} \\
    \gantttitle{October}{4}
    \gantttitle{November}{4} 
    \gantttitle{December}{4}  

    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{8}\\
    \ganttbar{Task 1}{1}{2} \\ 
    \ganttbar{Task 2}{3}{4} \\ 
    \ganttbar{Task 3}{5}{6}\\ 
    \ganttbar{Task 4}{1}{8} \\ 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

Now, I would like to be able to add the resources assigned to each task by inserting an inline label right of each bar. I have had a look at `/pgfgantt/bar label`, which offers a number of configurations for adjusting labels associated with a bar, but I cannot find a way to use it for having two labels (offline and inline) in one label. Is there any way to do this using `pgfgantt`?

This picture shows the compiled code from above plus red labels indicating what is it that I want to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site, freieschaf. Please could you provide a compilable LaTeX document (starting with `\documentclass` and so on) that shows what you have got so far, and perhaps an annotated picture to clarify exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks @JohnWickerson! I edited my question with your suggestions, hope it is easier to understand now. I did not attach the picture directly because I need higher reputation to do so.

Comment: There is `progress label` and various keys/styles to change its appearance.

Comment: I see now that you actually have emptied `progress label text={}` in the optional argument to the `ganttchart` environment …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code (Update)

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\makeatletter
\ganttset{
    prog default/.initial=100,
    prog/.code={
        \pgfutil@in@{:}{#1}
        \ifpgfutil@in@
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{@prog={#1}}
        \else
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{@prog={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfgantt/prog default}:#1}}
        \fi
    },
    @prog/.code args={#1:#2}{
        \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{progress=100, progress label text={#2 (#1\,\%)}}
    }
}
\makeatother
\ganttset{progress label anchor/.append style={text=red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
                    y unit chart=0.5cm,
                    vgrid={draw=none, dotted},
                    hgrid, 
                    title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
                    title left shift=.05,
                    title right shift=-.05,
                    title height=1,
                    bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
                    incomplete/.style={fill=white},
                    progress label text={},
                    bar height=0.7,
                    group right shift=0,
                    group top shift=.6,
                    group height=.3,
                    group peaks={}{}{.2},
                    ]{12}

    \gantttitle{2012}{12} \\
    \gantttitle{October}{4}
    \gantttitle{November}{4} 
    \gantttitle{December}{4} \\

    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{8}\\
    \ganttbar[prog=50:  Resource 1]{Task 1}{1}{2} \\ 
    \ganttbar[prog=     Resource 2]{Task 2}{3}{4} \\ 
    \ganttbar[prog=     Resource 3]{Task 3}{5}{6}\\ 
    \ganttbar[prog=50:  Resource 1, progress label anchor/.append style={below=4pt}]{Task 4}{1}{8} \\ 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\makeatletter
\ganttset{
    prog default/.initial=100,
    prog/.code={
        \pgfutil@in@{:}{#1}
        \ifpgfutil@in@
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{@prog={#1}}
        \else
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{@prog={\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfgantt/prog default}:#1}}
        \fi
    },
    @prog/.code args={#1:#2}{
        \edef\pgf@tempa{#1}%
        \ifx\pgf@tempa\tikz@nonetext
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{progress={100},progress label text={#2}}
        \else
            \pgfqkeysalso{/pgfgantt}{progress={#1},progress label text={#2 (##1\,\%)}}
        \fi
    }
}
\makeatother
\ganttset{progress label anchor/.append style={text=red}}
\begin{document}
\begin{ganttchart}[y unit title=0.4cm,
                    y unit chart=0.5cm,
                    vgrid={draw=none, dotted},
                    hgrid, 
                    title label anchor/.style={below=-1.6ex},
                    title left shift=.05,
                    title right shift=-.05,
                    title height=1,
                    bar/.style={fill=gray!50},
                    incomplete/.style={fill=white},
                    progress label text={},
                    bar height=0.7,
                    group right shift=0,
                    group top shift=.6,
                    group height=.3,
                    group peaks={}{}{.2},
                    ]{12}

    \gantttitle{2012}{12} \\
    \gantttitle{October}{4}
    \gantttitle{November}{4} 
    \gantttitle{December}{4} \\

    \ganttgroup{Group 1}{1}{8}\\
    \ganttbar[prog=50:  Resource 1]{Task 1}{1}{2} \\ 
    \ganttbar[prog=     Resource 2]{Task 2}{3}{4} \\ 
    \ganttbar[prog=none:Resource 3]{Task 3}{5}{6}\\ 
    \ganttbar[prog=50:  Resource 1, progress label anchor/.append style={below=4pt}]{Task 4}{1}{8} \\ 
\end{ganttchart}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Yes, that looks quite good, I will look at it carefully in a while. But actually, resources and their percentages don't have anything to do with the progress of a task: a resource works on the task, and its dedication (the percentage I added) means how much of their work effort goes into that task. I don't want to use progress on my chart so that's why it was empty in the `gantchart` options. Other than that, this could be a decent solution if I set progress=100 in every bar.

Comment: Well, yes, then just use `progress label text=Resource 1 (50\,\%)` for every bar. I have updated my answer. This way you do only have to specify Resource and (optional) the percentage.