# pgfgantt: remove line between 'year' and 'month' in title

Tags: pgfgantt

I want to remove the blank line between 'years' and 'months' in a pgfgantt chart.

What's the easiest way to do this?

This MWE shows the blank line that I want to remove:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[
  time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
  time slot unit=month
]{2019-01}{2020-09}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=letter} \\
  \ganttgroup[]{foo}{2019-07}{2020-03} \\  
  \ganttgroup[]{bar}{2020-01}{2020-07} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the manual, there is the key `y unit title` that controls the height of these elements, and `title height`, which determines the fraction to which they fill that "rule". If you set `title height=1`, there won't be an empty line, but the size may be too generous so you may want to reduce it a bit by saying `y unit title=5mm`.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}

\begin{document}

\begin{ganttchart}[title height=1,y unit title=5mm,
  time slot format=isodate-yearmonth,
  time slot unit=month
]{2019-01}{2020-09}
\gantttitlecalendar{year, month=letter} \\
  \ganttgroup[]{foo}{2019-07}{2020-03} \\  
  \ganttgroup[]{bar}{2020-01}{2020-07} \\
\end{ganttchart}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your answer helped me realise my problem was elsewhere: I am also using this code https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113227/pgfgantt-two-labels-for-one-bar-in-gantt-chart?rq=1 , which pushes the foo bar up into the months